# Why are the top: and left: properties inconsistent in my HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css, positioning

In my HTML page I have a bunch of pictureframe images I'm trying to line up on a shelf image, I'm trying to complete this by generating top: and left: in px the position of each image with javascript. Each img element is identical with the exception of its ID and its top: and left: position, but for some weird reason left:60px will be a different distance from the left of one element to another. The image provided demonstrates this.

Here is my css for the shelf div they are contained in. Each of the img elements have position relative

```
#theShelf {
    background-image: url(sprites/shelf2.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: contain;
    height: 1920px;
    width: 1080px; 
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
```

I was expecting an element with the same top:px and left:px properties in the same div, with the same dimensions and properties to be in the same place. But it seems many of these elements have inconsistent positions to their numeric values. I have tried changing the position: type of each element to everything I can think of and nothing seems to work.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`position: relative` means "Work out where this element would be if it wasn't positioned, then move it from that location".

If you have two `<img>` elements next to each other without positioning then the browser will render them *next to each other* (i.e. not overlapping on the same spot).

To use your approach you should be looking at setting `position: relative` on a parent element to establish a containing block and then using `position: absolute` to lay out the individual images within it.

You might be better off not using positioning and switching to [grid](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Grids) instead.

Comment: This feels bad because I spent a little bit of time programming this item class in javascript so it would fit on the shelf. But... Grids work like magic, it's perfect, and definitely, the way to go. Also, I understand how position relative works now, thank you.